# Dojo menu bar item stay focused after the page is closed

Tags: javascript, selection, dojo, menuitem

- I have dijit.MenuBar with some menu bar items.
- On clicking of the menu bar item, a popup page gets opened.
- After closing the popup-ed, the menu bar item is still in focus.
- My need is, after the popup page get closed, the menu bar item should not be in focus.

Here is my menu bar:

```
<div class="claro" id="menuDiv21" onclick="setWidgetproperty(this.id,'x','navMenu21');" onmousedown="setMenuBarProperty('navMenu21');" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="border:1px dotted white; left: auto; position: absolute; top: 620px;">
     <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBar" id="navMenu21" style="font-size:11pt;" title="MenuBar">
          <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="SearchMenu21" onclick="getWorklistManagerSearch('htmlTable2');setMenuId(this.id);" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="SearchMenu21" name="search5.png" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/search.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               Search
          </div>
          <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="TaskMenu21" onclick="setMenuId(this.id);" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="TaskMenu21" name="task6.png" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/task.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               Task
          </div>
          <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="AssignMenu21" onclick="javascript:popupwindow('assign.jsp', 'Assign', 900, 550)" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="AssignMenu21" name="assign7.png" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/assign.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               Assign
          </div>
          <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="ModifyMenu21" onclick="getWorklistManagerModify();" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="ModifyMenu21" name="modify8.jpg" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/modify.jpg" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               Modify
          </div>
          <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="OrderMenu21" onclick="setMenuId(this.id);" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="OrderMenu21" name="order9.jpg" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/order.jpg" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               Order
          </div>
          <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="HistoryMenu21" onclick="getWorklistManagerHistory();" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="HistoryMenu21" name="history10.png" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/history.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               History
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide a running jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

If your menu item opened a dijit/Dialog, the Dialog's default behavior is to re-focus the item which launched it when the Dialog is closed.

This behavior is driven by a property on Dialog called `refocus` which defaults to `true`.

If you and when you create your Dialog you pass in `{refocus:false}` the behavior will be turned off.